# how to use cache data in mvc architecture

Tags: node.js, caching, express, model-view-controller

As the title suggest. I'm trying to figure out where I should cache data in my node.js application.

I'm using a express.js and controllers to handle the routes in the application. The controller for a particular route will get data via the model layer using REST API and then it uses handlebars for the view rendering on the server.

For this particular route, I'm displaying a menu and the data I have got for this has been done in the model and a remote REST call.

When the user select different items in the menu, I do not want to make a new REST call to get the same data for the menu again, I just need to get the data for this menu once since it will never change.

I need to find out a way to cache it, but do not know where I should implement it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could just cache the response from the REST API or DB lookup using a memory-store like Redis or Memcached, both have good modules available on npm - ([Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis), [memcached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached)).

You would need to attempt to fetch the data from the memory-store (in your controller), if no matching data was found, you would make the request to the API or database to get the data, and then store it in your chosen memory-store so future requests will hit the cache.

*note:* There are also some pure JavaScript caches available such as [memory-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache) or [lru-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache) if you don't want to add an additional application.